# Java: for each within for each?

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach

so I was wondering if it's correct to make two for each in a row. In World I have an `ArrayList<House>` and in each `House` there's an `ArrayList<Furniture>`. I want to compare all furnitures in all houses with each other (said comparing method is done). Can I make:

```
  for (House h: _housesWorld)
      for (House h2: _housesWorld)
          i = compare(h, h2);
```

Or if I cannot make a for each within a for each, what can I do to compare all the houses with each other?

Comment: Did you try to run that?

Comment: you should use a normal for loop instead of foreach.

Comment: You can do it, but why ? Also you are looping over _housesWorld and you clearly declared h to represent the value in your primary ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to compare elements of the ArrayList you can use nested for loop

```
for(int i=0; i<_houseWorld.length;i++)
  for(int j=1; j<_houseWorld.length;j++)
    {
      flag=compare(_houseWorld.get(i),_houseWorld.get(j));

    }
 }
```